# Apache2 mod_wsgi 403 forbidden error

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I had it configured right, but then I decided to reinstall my Debian (switching from wheezy to jessie version by the way). Here's the problem:

I have a python mod_wsgi application at: `/mnt/doc/Python/www/index.py`.

```
$ ls -l / | grep mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 sty 12 09:36 mnt

$ ls -l /mnt
drwxrwxrwx 1 sven sven 20480 sty  7 19:34 doc

$ ls -l /mnt/doc/Python/www/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 1 sven sven 4096 Jan  3 19:52 core
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sven sven    0 Dec 22 13:25 __init__.py
drwxrwxrwx 1 sven sven    0 Dec 24 00:11 silva
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sven sven  984 Dec 22 13:47 silva.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sven sven  697 Dec 25 13:32 txt
```

All subdirectories have the same permissions as `/mnt/doc`, but still I get 403 Forbidden error, when trying to open the site. It's configuration below:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /huh /mnt/doc/Python/www/index.py                 
<Directory /mnt/doc/Python/www>                                   
    Order allow,deny                                                            
    Allow from all                                                              
</Directory>
```

When trying to open the page, the following message appears in Apache2 log:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 15269:tid 140518201730816] [client ::1:44130] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /mnt/doc/Python/www/index.py
```

I'm pretty sure that I copied previous configuration quite exactly. Did anything change recently?

EDIT: I neglected to add that I use Python 3.3 and libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 Debian package.

Comment: What does print `ls -l /mnt/doc/Python/silva-rerum/`

Comment: Added the result to the original post.

Comment: Do you use Apache 2.4.x?

Comment: Directory `/mnt/doc/Python/silva-rerum` is not in Apache config. Is this a typo?

Comment: Yeah, it's a typo, of course. Sorry. Corrected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved it finally. pxl was half-right, because not only `Allow from all` should be replaced by `Require all granted`, but also `Order allow,deny` is no longer necessary. It turns out to be the reason for my error. Complete script alias config should be like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /huh /mnt/doc/Python/www/index.py                 
<Directory /mnt/doc/Python/www>                                   
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And it works.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `Allow from all` with `Require all granted`.

Reference for Apache module [`mod_authz_core`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requiredirectives)

Comment: Yeah, I found that directive somewhere on the web and tried it. No luck. Still the same error occurs.

Comment: And what's more, when I replaced `Allow from all` with `Require all granted`, also the `/` of my localhost (which is plain HTML document) returns Forbidden error, whereas with `Allow from all` it worked nice...

Answer (score 3):

I wrote like below,

```
    WSGIScriptAlias /hello /home/myself/projects/hello/hello.wsgi
    <Directory /home/myself/projects/hello>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

and it works